# How do I Add a searchbar with NSPredicate

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, searchbar

I am getting an error when add the

`-(void) statement`.

"`use of undeclared identifier "filterContentForSearchText`"

```
//start of Predicate
- (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope
{
    NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate
                                    predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains[cd] %@",
                                    searchText];

    searchResults = [recipes filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate];
}
```

end of search

Comment: Is your declaration signature found to match this implementation? And also is this method called correctly?

Comment: I just started learning a few months ago. Im following a tutorial here http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-101-how-to-hide-tab-bar-navigation-controller/ and trying to do the same for my map.

Comment: the code works with the tutorial, however when I try and implement it into my code I get an error

Comment: You say you have the tutorial with you. Then compare both codes and see what's different and understand why it is so.

Comment: I did, but after making the changes Im getting the error and in the sample it is not declared anywhere in the .h or .m files.

Comment: How do I get the links from the search results to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this [sample](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/58723521/SearchSample.zip), made using `NSPredicate`  if your array doesn't contain this kind of data, show us your data or array handling, which type of data you are having in your array.

Comment: lodgeList = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:
                
                 //Abingdon
                 @"Abingdon Lodge No. 48",
                 @"York Lodge No. 12",
                 
                 //Alberene
                 @"Alberene Lodge No. 277",
                
      
        
 nil];

Comment: and cityname = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:
                //Abingdon
                @"Abingdon, City",
                @"Abingdon, City",
                
                //Alberence
                @"Alberene, City",
nil]; Im also in storyboard format.

Comment: the array is similar to the one in sample code.. and which list u want to search `lodgeList` or `cityname`.. what it may be, handle the original & filtered list as in my sample code..

Comment: Lodgelist is the list that I what to be able to search.

Comment: have u made the changes to access the list as in the sample.. is it working for u?

Comment: Im getting this error now.. and Im using ARC.. so i had to change some of the code.                                                             int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([MOVAppDelegate class]));
    }
}

Comment: this is just the code for the app to start, main.m file.. just leave it as it was.. just check out code in `tableView` and `searchBar` delegates..

Comment: Dude you are the MAN!!!!!!!!!!! but after the search the links do not work.. how do I fix that?

Comment: you need to use the filtered list through out ur tableView delegates, even `didSelectRow` you might be missing some thing here..

Comment: I dont have a didselectRow and I don't see that in the sample code that you provided.. Please advise ... :)

Comment: - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{MOVDetailViewController * MDVC = [[MOVDetailViewController alloc] init]; MDVC = [segue destinationViewController];
    
    NSIndexPath * path = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    
    NSString * thelodge = [lodgeList objectAtIndex:path.row];
    MDVC.lodgeNumber = path.row;
    MDVC.lodgeName = thelodge;

Comment: in the above method.. in this line `NSString * thelodge = [lodgeList objectAtIndex:path.row];` whether `lodgeList` is filtered list or the original list..? it should be filtered list..

Comment: ok made that change, however the unfiltered list works.. but the search results don't

Comment: I ran the sample code you gave me and it does the same thing.. when the user clicks on the name nothing happens...

Comment: - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"segue" sender: self];
    }

}

Comment: code works I added this - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"segue" sender: self];
    }
}